# get current cart items to my custom checkout step magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, cart

I created a custom checkout step as per the [devdocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html) , now I need to get current cart items to my custom checkout step, how can I do that ?

checkout_index_index.xml

```
<item name="my-new-step" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Amsi_UserManagement/js/view/select-student-view</item>
    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1.5</item>
</item>
```

view/frontend/web/js/view/select-student-view.js

```
define(
    [
        'ko',
        'uiComponent',
        'underscore',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
    ],
    function (
        ko,
        Component,
        _,
        stepNavigator
    ) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Amsi_UserManagement/selectstudent'
            },
            isVisible: ko.observable(true),e: function () {
                this._super();
                stepNavigator.registerStep(
                    'select_student_step',
                    'select_student_step',
                    'Select Student',
                    this.isVisible,

                    _.bind(this.navigate, this),
                    15
                );

                return this;
            },

            navigate: function () {
                console.log('navigation is good');
            },
            navigateToNextStep: function () {
                stepNavigator.next();
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if anyone looking for solution, you can access all checkout related data from   `window.checkoutConfig` so I added new function in my *select-student-view.js* file

```
getCartItems: function () {
   return window.checkoutConfig.quoteItemData;
}
```

Comment: Hi, @Ebin Manuval I am a beginner in Magento. Can you please tell me how to call this and display cart items on the Html page of my custom step?